# Can eval be applied on a compiled ast node have a local context

Tags: python

I am working on a new Python to JavaScript [compiler](http://www.transcrypt.org), that generates special code for __pragma__ statements that contain compiler directives. To be able to do that I have to evaluate part of the Ast using a context containing a local function.

My code is:

```
  eval (compile (ast.Expression (arg), '<string>', 'eval'), globals (), locals ())
```

where arg is an expression node holding a call to a local function 'include'. If I inspect locals (), 'include' is indeed there. But 'eval' complains:

```
name 'include' is not defined.
```

I've looked at a an example suppied at [Eli Bendersky's website](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/28/python-internals-working-with-python-asts). He does about the same thing, only doesn't supply a local context. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

[EDIT]

It's all working perfectly now (Thanks Martijn!). I also forgot that literal keys of a dictionary need to be quoted. Programming to much JS these days...

```
    def emitKwargDict ():
        self.emit ('__kwargdict__ (')

        hasSeparateKeyArgs = False
        hasKwargs = False
        for keyword in node.keywords:
            if keyword.arg:
                hasSeparateKeyArgs = True
            else:
                hasKwargs = True
                break   # **kwargs is always the last arg

        if hasSeparateKeyArgs:  
            if hasKwargs:
                self.emit ('__merge__ (')
            self.emit ('{{')    # Allways if hasSeparateKeyArgs

        for keywordIndex, keyword in enumerate (node.keywords):
            if keyword.arg:
                self.emitComma (keywordIndex)
                self.emit ('{}: ', keyword.arg)
                self.visit (keyword.value)
            else:
                # It's the **kwargs arg, so the last arg
                # In JavaScript this must be an expression denoting an Object (sometimes specialized as kwargdict)
                # The keyword args in there have to be added to the __kwargdict__ as well   
                if hasSeparateKeyArgs:
                    self.emit ('}}, ')          
                self.visit (keyword.value)

        if hasSeparateKeyArgs:
            if hasKwargs:
                self.emit (')')     # Terminate merge
            else:
                self.emit ('}}')    # Only if not terminated already because hasKwargs

        self.emit (')')

    def include (fileName):
        searchedIncludePaths = []
        for searchDir in self.module.program.moduleSearchDirs:
            filePath = '{}/{}'.format (searchDir, fileName)
            if os.path.isfile (filePath):
                return open (filePath) .read ()
            else:
                searchedIncludePaths.append (filePath)
        else:
            raise utils.Error (
                moduleName = self.module.metadata.name,
                lineNr = self.lineNr,
                message = '\n\tAttempt to include file: {}\n\tCan\'t find any of:\n\t\t{}\n'.format (
                    node.args [0], '\n\t\t'. join (searchedIncludePaths)
                )
            )

    if type (node.func) == ast.Name:
        if node.func.id == 'property':
            self.emit ('{0}.call ({1}, {1}.{2}'.format (node.func.id, self.getscope (ast.ClassDef) .name, node.args [0].id))
            if len (node.args) > 1:
                self.emit (', {}.{}'.format (self.getscope (ast.ClassDef) .name, node.args [1].id))
            self.emit (')')
            return
        elif node.func.id == '__pragma__':
            if node.args [0] .s == 'kwargs':        # Start emitting kwargs code for FunctionDef's
                self.allowKeywordArgs = True
            elif node.args [0] .s == 'nokwargs':    # Stop emitting kwargs code for FunctionDef's
                self.allowKeywordArgs = False
            elif node.args [0] .s == 'js':          # Include JavaScript code literally in the output
                self.emit ('\n{}\n', node.args [1] .s.format (* [
                    eval (
                        compile (
                            ast.Expression (arg),
                            '<string>',
                            'eval'
                        ),
                        {},
                        {'include': include}
                    )
                    for arg in node.args [2:]
                ]))
            elif node.args [0] .s == 'alias':
                self.aliases [args [1]] = args [2]
            return
        elif node.func.id == '__new__':
            self.emit ('new ')
            self.visit (node.args [0])
            return

    self.visit (node.func)

    for index, expr in enumerate (node.args):
        if type (expr) == ast.Starred:
            self.emit ('.apply (null, ')    # Note that in generated a.b.f (), a.b.f is a bound function already

            for index, expr in enumerate (node.args):
                if index:
                    self.emit ('.concat (')
                if type (expr) == ast.Starred:
                    self.visit (expr)
                else:
                    self.emit ('[')
                    self.visit (expr)
                    self.emit (']')
                if index:
                    self.emit (')')

            if node.keywords:
                self.emit ('.concat ([')    # At least *args was present before this point
                emitKwargDict ()
                self.emit ('])')

            self.emit (')')         
            break;
    else:   
        self.emit (' (')
        for index, expr in enumerate (node.args):
            self.emitComma (index)
            self.visit (expr)

        if node.keywords:
            self.emitComma (len (node.args))
            emitKwargDict ()

        self.emit (')')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `NameError` exception, which indicates that the name is looked up as a *global*, not a local. Put the name in your `globals` dictionary.

Comment: Your posted code isn't valid; you are missing a `)` on the `compile()` call.

Comment: Also, I'm very sorry, but I'm not going to read through that much code to figure out what you are doing and why it requires `locals()` to be passed in explicitly (it'll default to the same dictionary as the globals argument if omitted). You may want to stick to the [PEP 8 Python styleguide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you are asking people to review your code, it is rather hard to read as is.

Comment: Well, thanks anyhow, you've been a great help. As for the style guide, I am usually dealing with a mix of C++, JavaScript and Python, so I have to compromise there.

Comment: Problem solved: dict keys have to be between quotes. I program to much JS these days...